# Can anyone tell me if and why I should void using ViewData in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

This has probably come before and is probably very subjective.  I have been tols to avoid using ViewData and use a FromViewModel class to pass informaiton to the view istead.

Are there any major advantages of this approach?

Thanks

Davy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewData is not strong typed, whilst Models are. So Models are less error-prone and more clear.